# Как отключить вертикальную полосу Atom editor?

Tags: atom

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не понял как включил, и не могу понять как выключить эту чудесную помогающую полоску.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom > Open Your Stylesheet

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .wrap-guide {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Всё очень просто.
Settings => Packages => В строке поиска вводим **wrap** => Disable => Наслаждаемся

Answer (score 3):

Данная вертикальная линия отрисовывается по умолчанию на расстоянии 80 символов от начала файла. Это кастомное значение для настройки Preferred Line Length во вкладке Settings>Editor, если будет активна настройка Soft Wrap At Preferred Line Length, то все символы будут автоматически переносится на новую строку по достижению этого ограничения.

Истоки этого значения идут со времён перфокарт, на которых было 80 колонок для задания кодировки символов.